# Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined in NgbTypeahead

Tags: angular, rxjs, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to use the typeahead directive of ng-bootstrap. I have the following HTML snippet:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="payee" autofocus [ngbTypeahead]="searchPayee">
```

accompanied by the following property in the component, just like [the first example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples) from ng-bootstrap official docs:

```js
searchPayee = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
        : ['aaa', 'bbbb'].filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10)));
  }
```

However, when executed, I get the following error. Any ideas what I am missing here?

```
TransactionModalComponent.html:50 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
    at NgbTypeahead.ngOnInit (ng-bootstrap.js:10414)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31909)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44366)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44305)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45327)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45270)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MyComponent.html:50)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45258)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44270)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
```

Comment: The only thing i see differently is the fact you're not using an NgModel, but i doubt that that is the problem. Does this always happen, or just in the beginning?

Comment: Your not returning anything in `searchPayee`. Either use `return` or remove the `{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In their example, `text$.pipe` is being returned because they're not using a block statement (curly braces).

In your example, the expression is using a block statement (curly braces), so you have to explicitly use a `return text$.pipe` so that it is returned.

Example:

```js
searchPayee = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    return text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
        : ['aaa', 'bbbb'].filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10)));
  }
```

or, without the block (as in the ngb example):

```js
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
        : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
    )
```

---

Essentially, arrow functions work like this:

```js
// returns val
const foo = (val) => val;

// returns val
const bar = (val) => {
  return val;
}

// returns nothing
const baz = (val) => {
  val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, this shouldn't be happening.
You could always try adding an NgModel,
but i suggest you do the following to make sure it doesn't happen:

```
searchPayee = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
   if(text$ === null || text$ === undefined) return;
   text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
      : ['aaa', 'bbbb'].filter(v => 
            v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10)));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't an answer to the above but the google search brings you here and in case someone else comes here looking for help...

In my case, I had a parenthesis set that was not needed.  Right after 'search' in the example below.

From
`<input [(ngModel)]="searchText" type="text" [ngbTypeahead]="search()" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Search..." />`

To
`<input [(ngModel)]="searchText" type="text" [ngbTypeahead]="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Search..." />`